# Attach Porch Roof Beam to Side of House

Tags: roof, beam, porch

The porch is 15'x20' and will be connected to the back of the house. The concrete piers, ledger, joists, and beams have already been installed. I'm now moving to install 4x4 posts and (2) 2x8 roof beams on top of the posts. I need to make a connection between the beams at two places to the flat side of the back of the house. It's been suggested I use a joist hanger like those used for the deck joists to connect the beam to the backside of the house after removing the siding that is in place. Is this the correct connection bracket or are there other options?

I've attached a picture to explain in better detail hopefully. I will be building a gabled roof on top of these beams and was planning to connect the first set of rafters to the side of the house as well with lags.

Thanks[image: Porch overhead layout]

Comment: Your drawing shows a fairly standard porch arrangement. What it doesn't show is the details of your home's wall and roof structure, the location of any windows, doors, plumbing stacks, etc. Without those, any advice given can only be somewhat general.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have posts at the face of the existing wall. If that's the case, you don't really need to attach the beams other than to hold them in place in a superficial manner.

Otherwise, joist hangers or full bearing on framing in the wall. In either case you need suitable backing structure on which to mount the hangers or bear the beams. If you don't have studs in the right locations, look into top-bearing hangers that you can fasten to the top of your wall plates.

The fact that one beam appears to connect at an outside corner may complicate things a bit. You won't have room for a standard hanger. You might be able to attach around the corner by flattening out one leg of the hanger. That also may be a good location to cut into the corner stud cluster and bear directly.

Comment: If the beam will bear on the posts I don't need to be as concerned with how the beam ties into the house? The side of the home is plywood covered by siding. If this is the case, I can attach the ends of the beam with nails directly to the plywood around the house?

Comment: I assumed that you'd be fastening the posts to the wall. If you do, The beam only needs minor anchoring to the post and/or the wall.